# Supersymmetry with two independent supercharges, $\mathcal N=4$, or $\mathcal N=(2,2)$, and physical significance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, supersymmetry, parity

My question is about a specific example of supersymmetry in quantum mechanics. I am not an expert on SUSY, and I would like to have some insights on this.
Imagine you have a non-Hermitian supercharge $Q$ satisfying the algebra
\begin{equation}
\{ P, Q \}=0,\,\,\,\,
Q^2=( Q^\dagger)^2=0, \,\,\, \{Q,Q^\dagger\}=H,
\end{equation}
where $P$ is the parity operator and $H$ is the Hamiltonian.

To be specific, let's assume that $H$ is a quantum mechanical Hamiltonian (e.g., Schrödinger) in one dimension.

In this case, since the supercharge is not-Hermitian and can be written as a sum of two Hermitian operators, one says that the Hamiltonian has $\mathcal N=2$ supersymmetry.

Imagine now that one has a second supercharge $Q'$ such that $[Q,Q']\neq0$ and $\{Q,Q'\}\neq0$, satisfying the same algebra
\begin{equation}
\{ P, Q' \}=0,\,\,\,\,
Q^{\prime 2}=(Q^{\prime\dagger})^2=0, \,\,\, \{Q',Q^{\prime\dagger}\}=H,
\end{equation}

My question(s):
In this case, one is talking about $\mathcal N=4$, $\mathcal N=(2,2)$ or else?
What is the physical significance of supersymmetry with respect to two independent supercharges?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43644

Comment: @NiharKarve I am sorry but it is not a duplicate. I am posting a specific example and asking about it. I think the questions should be reopened

Comment: @NiharKarve I am asking about supersymmetry in quantum mechanics, the other question (and answer) is concerned more about supergravity. The other questions asks about N=1 and N=2 but I am asking about the difference between N=2 and N=(2,2)

Comment: The difference is summarised [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107327)

Comment: I still do not agree on closing my question. Think about my questions as a homework question. I am learning about supersymmetry and I would like to have some insights. I read the other questions and answers on SUSY (before asking my question) and I am still do not understand whether one has N=4 or N=(2,2) and what is the meaning of it. Also, my question is specific to SUSY in quantum mechanics, while other questions asks about SUSY in quantum gravity. There can be differences.